# What should be the value of redirect URI in Google Developer console

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am running my project on localhost. My current project path on local system is http://localhost/upload_gd2/google-api/examples/user-example.php.

I have tried entering redirect URI but it shows following screen after clicking on accept button. It seems to be a small problem but i'm facing this issue from the last four days.

Please help to solve it. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What does it show when you click the accept button?

Comment: The second image Not Found The requested URL /user-example.php was not found on this server.

Comment: and redirected to http://localhost/user-example.php?code=4/xy9t4L6XR9KdzfQVUQ2lC4wvEDF_7ISqa463UlVlFIM#

Comment: then you added a redirect uri of localhost/user-example.php   check google developer console again.

Comment: In both places it is http://localhost/user-example.php

Comment: but the same error message. Please help to solve it....

Comment: Redirect uri must match the file location on the server you said it was "http ://localhost/upload_gd2/google-api/examples/user-example.php"  then the redirect uri on google developer console must be http ://localhost/upload_gd2/google-api/examples/user-example.php